# ESLint: make it understand /// <reference path directive in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

Is there any way in VS Code how to make ESLint understand `/// <reference path` directive so it does not throw `no-undef` error for variable/function defined in referenced JS file?

It seems to work somehow, but not fully:
VS Code function description but eslint error
[image: VS Code function description but eslint error]

Comment: This is a good question, but please dont use screenshots for code or error messages. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Thanks for reply. I understand why not to do that, but how could I show in this very case that it works in one way and not in other without showing on picture? The code itself in this case is not important at all.